# Android mediaplayer endless buffering

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing online streaming player on Android. I found that mediaplayer wont ever stop buffering! It reads 100% of buffer and keeps doing 'something', because stream can only be read only once and there nothing left to buffer...
I see that

```
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer player, int percent)
```

is called endlessly with percent = 100. It drains battery over one night.  Am I doing something wrong or there is some reasonable explanation on this? It seems that buffering can not be canceled, the only way to stop it is to reset mediaplayer itself. I need some way to stop this endless 'buffering'!

This how I init mediaplayer

```
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamUrl);
mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Log messages I see:

```
10-30 08:45:21.169: D/MediaPlayer(13217): Message: MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE(3), ext1=93, ext2=0x0
10-30 08:45:22.169: D/MediaPlayer(13217): Message: MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE(3), ext1=100, ext2=0x0
10-30 08:45:23.169: D/MediaPlayer(13217): Message: MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE(3), ext1=100, ext2=0x0
10-30 08:45:24.172: D/MediaPlayer(13217): Message: MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE(3), ext1=100, ext2=0x0
10-30 08:45:25.172: D/MediaPlayer(13217): Message: MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE(3), ext1=100, ext2=0x0
...
```

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out? I am developing an app where a video is played through a MediaPlayer in a Service and I realized that after leaving it "paused" it was draining battery even when the phone is screen off and supposedly asleep! Stopping and resetting the MediaPlayer seems to have fixed it but it would still be preferable if I could instead leave it paused, as it takes longer to resume if I have to reinitialize the player.

Comment: I figured out that it behaved like this only on my Huawei phone (at least any other device i tested worked correctly). In the end I made it like this: if player is paused for some time and is buffering then i reset the player.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's not a good idea to leave the MediaPlayer paused while not in use. It may work sometimes, but Android is going to take back those resources eventually. It's simply bad practice not to clean up when your app isn't active.

That said, I believe what it's doing is maintaining an open socket with the server, probably sending the buffering notification whenever it pings to make sure the socket is still open. HTTP streaming is too simple a protocol to do what you ask. But you have at least one option to make it work. You can insert a proxy that will allow you to cache the stream and playback simultaneously. You will have to be clever about dealing with what happens when the user exits before the stream is fully cached, but it can work. At that point, the MediaPlayer is reduced to local file playback, which you can stop and seek to the correct point when the app is opened again. It provides a means of managing resources and network communication better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will end media player when pressing back.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    mp.stop();
    mp.reset();
            this.finish();

}
```

Comment: The point is I don't want to reset mediaplayer. Desired behavior: User plays track -> Press pause -> Leaves app -> Comes back in a few hours -> continues playing.

Comment: mp.pause(); may be enough.

Comment: Well pause() does work and I get this desired behavior, except mediaplayer keeps 'buffering' and drains battery if I pause(). If I  reset mp, endless buffering stops, BUT I wont be able to continue playing. It would be perfect if buffering would stop when it reaches 100%, but it does't (for some magic reason...). I'm looking for nice way to stop buffering without resetting the mediaplayer.

Comment: save the position where the MP is, when the user comes back, use SeekTo to go back to that position.